# Azure package missing project dlls

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

My worker role will not run and is constantly recycling. I get a filenotfoundexception which points me in the direction of missing assemblies. All works fine locally of course.

I've gone through the references for the worker role project and made sure that copy local is true where necessary. By RDP'ing to the VM I can see that when I deploy my worker role several of my solution's project dlls (like my entity and data dlls) are missing and are not in the package. I don't understand why they would be missing. They are compiled for .Net 4, "any cpu" and copy local is true. What am I missing?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 2):

this happens if your roles reference one another. For example, I had a worker role and a web role in my azure project. The webrole was referencing the worker role. As soon as I moved the reference the packaging worked correctly.

Comment: This was driving me crazy - was giving me a FileNotFound exception on the role starting because the DLL was missing. Thank you!

Comment: Burned a day on this. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: WorkerRoleA had reference to WorkerRoleB. Moved all common code into a library project and added reference from WorkerRoleA and WorkerRoleB to the common library. Strangely, this only fixed the problem after "clean solution". "rebuild solution" wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get to the bottom of this but what I did do that solved it was to create another worker role. I did also noticed that I hadn't included the app.config with copy always set correctly which was a different problem but worth noting for others finding this.